# Applying Eclat Algorithm on dataset. and showing KeyError: '0'

Tags: database, algorithm, transactions, bigdata, apriori

I am applying for Eclat Algorithm.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV8OR.png)
but

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXmD6.png)

KeyError: '0'

What is the possible cause and solution?

I am new to python and I am trying to generate frequent item sets from a log file using eclat. I am directly calling the eclat function from fim and passing the whole log file as a nested list. I want to use various options while calling eclat, like passing a file directly as input, passing output file name to write the results, min support, max item set size etc. Can someone tell how to pass the arguments to eclat that is being called as a function from fim? Attached image of the code

Comment: Please don't post code or error messages as image, [edit] and use text. (You can leave images as supporting info). Your code is missing.